# Cannot invoke """"""" is null

Tags: java, netbeans

El error me lo marca en el siguiente metodo:
En el if donde lo igualo al null pero no entiendo porque me lo toma como null aiuda :(

```
public static int b_m_sales() {
        int ind1 = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_sales.length; i++) {
            if (m_sales[i].getN_sale() == null) {
                ind1 = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ind1;
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y no sera que m_sales[i] es null????

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que el código esté causando una NullPointerException porque el método getN_sale() se llama en un elemento de la matriz m_sales que es nulo.

Podes comprobar si el objeto m_sales[i] es nulo antes de llamar al método getN_sale(), así:

```
if (m_sales[i] != null && m_sales[i].getN_sale() == null)
```